# View shows only half of width in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

I have one view controller,in that i have  1 UIButton ,when i click on that button one view opens ,but when i move it to landscape mode at that time the view shows only half of width  not full.what should i do?????

Thanks and welcome for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the autoresizing properties, i.e.

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

You should probably call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view after changing the orientation.

Comment: This code is not working for my view
see ,when i click on button one UIVIEWCONTROLLER is there.in that UIViewController one UIScrollview is there ,in that UISCROLLVIEW i added one image one UIButton ,one UITableview.what should i do?